# Passing key name dynamically

Tags: react-native

in my code i need to fetch data from multiple keys and here is my code

```
<CircularProgress
                  progressPercent={data[`successratio_${sig_name}`]}//this could me intra,short,long,mid
                  size={iconSize}
                  strokeWidth={5}
                  text={data[`successratio_${sig_name}`] + "%"}//this could me intra,short,long,mid
                  bgColor={isDarkMode ? colors.text : "#F4F4F4"}
                  pgColor={colors.buttonPrimary}
                  textColor={colors.text}
                />
```

SO in this case i have a variable(sig_name) with has the values of (intra,short,long,mid) and i passed that variable here in data[`successratio_${sig_name}`] but getting "undefined" as output. right now i am adding one 'data' but there is need of adding 2 data like data.data so how i will do that. pelase help.

Comment: post en example of your `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below way, might help you:

eg.

```
// varNameHere can be string as intra, short, long or mid

data[`successratio_${varNameHere}`]
```

Comment: didnt work. i tried but it is saying "undefined"

Comment: Can you update your code in your question?

Comment: ok one min. let me do it

Comment: i just updated it please check.

Comment: hello, i have noticed somthing i need to add data.data.successratio_short to get value. so please update your code accordingly please.

Answer (score 0):

Sort it out by myself updated code is below.

```
data?.data?.[`successratio_${varNameHere}`]
```